# Typescript: Extending Set in class causes error (Constructor Set requires 'new')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to implement some basic operations to the Set object like says [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set)

This is the code

```
export class Conjunto extends Set<any>{
  constructor(initialValues?) {
    super();
    return new Conjunto(initialValues);
  }

  isSuperset(subset) {
    //some code
  }
}
```

Do you guys have any idea to make it work? or am I doing something wrong?

For the moment I'm using the hack this guy found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10853)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to add functions to the Set prototype, or add polyfills to Set, you can do the following:

```
declare global {
  interface Set<T> {
      // polyfill
      isSuperset(subset: Set<T>) : boolean;
      // new function
      someNewFunc(): boolean;
  }
}

// add polyfill to the Set prototype as mentioned in the doc you provided: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set 
Set.prototype.isSuperset = function(subset) {
    for (var elem of subset) {
        if (!this.has(elem)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//add the new someNewFunc;
Set.prototype.someNewFunc = function() {
    // some logic here...
    return true;
}
```

to use:

```
stringSet = new Set<string>()
stringSet.isSuperset(someOtherSet);
stringSet.someNewFunc(); // returns true
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. Only one question more, how can I separate this from the app component to another file. I'm trying but it seems that only the interface is being exported

Comment: This is vanilla js, has to be included in the generated js file after transpiration. You can include it via webpack or whatever bundluer you are using. Using angular cli by chance?

Comment: after? But then I will not be able to take advantage of the vscode intellisense

Comment: No wait haha. I'm sorry. You're totally right. The interface is for the intellisense XD I get it. 

So I can see that the correct place is the **polyfills.ts** file.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems like you are using angular-cli. Then yes, polyfill.ts is the correct file. If you were not using the cli, you'll just have to find away for the Js code to be on the page before the angular code. But generally you'd add a new entry to webpack to generate a separate js bundle that you'd then include on the page.

Comment: yeah I'm using the cli v1.  Thanks