# Type checking Javascript with Typescript: subclassing raises error

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Starting with [version 1.12](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_12#_type-checking-for-javascript-files) Visual Studio Code can [typecheck](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files) .js files same as .ts files. For most cases, this is really neat, but I get an error I don't understand:

```
class FreezableSet extends Set {
    add (value) {
        if (!Object.isFrozen(this)) super.add(value);
        return this;
    }
    delete (value) {
        if (Object.isFrozen(this)) return false;
        return super.delete(value);
    }
    clear () {
        if (Object.isFrozen(this)) return;
        super.clear();
    }
}
```

The `Set` in the first line gets annotated with the following error:

> Base constructors must all have the same return type.

Just to be clear, the `Set` is the ES6 base collection type.

Using a `/** @augments {Set<any>} */` annotation, with or without braces, or annotating the methods, changes nothing.

Does anyone understand what that means? For all listed methods, I can see the infered types are identical to their super signatures.

- `(method) FreezableSet.add(value: any): this`
- `(method) FreezableSet.delete(value: any): boolean`
- `(method) FreezableSet.clear(): void`

Comment: See this post on extending Set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301849/typescript-extending-set-in-class-causes-error-constructor-set-requires-new

Comment: How does that relate? The methods all exist on Set and have the same signature.